# Open source project no longer in profile but visible in the generated PDF

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

On my profile edit page I am no longer shown any open source project (one or two were linked I think prior) because I removed them. But when I preview with **create pdf** I am still able to see one of them.

**UPDATE**

Now I've selected one project and all projects from my github account are displayed in the generated pdf.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Also with me. .

Comment: Perhaps the PDF files are cached? They do like to do that, you know.

Comment: No, because I checked this by adding a new project (not open source) and the deleted open source project was in the template. More so, this open source project was deleted a couple of weeks (or more) ago.

If it where cache the only way that could be true if each section is cached individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now deployed a fix to now only show selected projects on pdf export.